# Silent Installation - .net 4 prerequisite

Tags: logging, wix, custom-action

For silent installation if the .net4 Framework is not available , I need to add the message to log saying installation can continue only if .net4framework is installed.
Is this possible to implement via standard custom action which can be added to InstallExecuteSequence.

In the UI mode i use NETFRAMEWORK40FULL property to check the existence of dotnetframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with custom action type 19. Looks like you stopped only one step from your goal:

```
<CustomAction Id="DotNet4PrerequisiteAssert" Error=".NET 4 is not installed"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="DotNet4PrerequisiteAssert" After="AppSearch">NOT Installed AND NOT NETFRAMEWORK40FULL</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But I'm not sure why don't you use LaunchCondition instead of manual custom action. It should work in both UI and silent mode:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
<Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 4.0 client profile installed.' >
    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: Thanks Oleksandr. I will try with the custom action. I didnt get from the statement "you stopped only one step from your goal". In the UI mode , iam showing a dialog with the link that would direct to the download page , in the silent mode , just  wanted to write to the logs and aborting the installation

Comment: "you stopped only one step from your goal" - I mean you described everything you need actually in the question. Just the custom action type left to specify  =). Launch condition will also show message in UI mode and generate an error in log in silent mode. The only difference is that you won't get link to download page